# Stored Procedure Performance Issue

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a stored procedure that is stalling the database. If the stored procedure is run as a query, the results arrive nearly instantly. If the stored procedure is run as a stored procedure, with it's single parameter, it stalls the database. I'm at a loss as to how to fix the issue since there isn't anything wrong with the query on its own, just as a stored procedure. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post both of the actual execution plans for 1) the ad-hoc query and 2) the stored procedure execution?

Comment: Smells like [parameter sniffing](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=parameter+sniffing).